# Why does my JSFiddle work, but not my Codepen?

Tags: vue.js, jsfiddle, codepen

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnonymousCaptain/wqypr814/33/)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AnonymousCaptain/pen/WNQapaa)

What is missing?

```
Please see my two previous links.
```

Comment: Hi, You are missing dependency here- >. Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue2Leaflet is not defined 
 at pen.js:-15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt add resources to your Codepen, i added from jsfiddle and now [codepen](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/bGVmWqJ) works,

```
https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js
https://unpkg.com/vue2-leaflet@0.0.58/dist/vue2-leaflet.js

https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css
```

Comment: Thanks! How come the JSFiddle doesn't show any dependencies?

Comment: About first question, JSFiddle dependencies show on left side , below `Resources` title, and about second question i just copied jsfiddle resources to codepen